# Custom Kafka Deserializer ignores null messages

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, deserialization, spring-kafka

I'm using Kotlin Spring Boot and I have a custom Kafka Deserialiser. The issue is that the custom `Deserializer` complete ignores messages that have null values. Is there a way for null messages to go through the `deserialize` method?

I'm setting the custom Deserialiserlizer on application.yaml

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      value-deserializer: mypackage.CustomDeserializer
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

And the CustomDeserializer is like

```
class CustomDeserializer : Deserializer<Result<MyData?>> {
    private val log = logger()

    override fun deserialize(topic: String?, data: ByteArray?): Result< MyData?> {
    //deserialisation logic
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you have in your custom serializer ? **CustomDeserializer**

Comment: @YassineCHABLI I've updated the description. The deserialize won't be triggered at all, if the message is null.

Comment: I see the same behavior when implementing a Serializer in Kotlin. Not using spring

Answer (score 1):

This is not expected behavior. [See Kafka Source Code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArrayDeserializer.java) that does accept null byte arrays.

Perhaps you do need to implement the class in Java since `ByteArray?` and `byte[]` may not compile to the same value?

Alternatively, rather than write your own, you could use existing Deserializers that are based on Avro, Protobuf, or JSONSchema / plain JSON data (Spring has a plain-JSON one, Confluent has the rest).

Comment: Kotlin ByteArray? is equal to Java byte[]. See the kdoc of the type: `An array of bytes. When targeting the JVM, instances of this class are represented as `byte[]`.`

Comment: Apologies, I do not use Kotlin, but doesn't it have some logic around null-safety? There was no producer code shared that sends a null value